# is there any easy way to get N-level of directories from bottom?

Tags: python

I knew we can use os.walk to get bottom-most directories by checking if the dirname is empty. I could then try to slice the bottom-most directory path to get the N-level bottom-most dirs.

For example, the bottom-most path is: `['a/b/c/d/e/f', 'a/b/c/d/g/h/i/j']`, Then I can get a 3rd bottom-most dirs: `['a/b/c/d', 'a/b/c/d/g/h']`

Is there any more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I think your way is really nice.

Comment: @EllaShar the problem is that, in most cases, this is very redundant, since lots of subdirs share the same parent dirs.

Comment: But you must check the subdirs and their parents to know that. Lets see if anyone comes up with an answer.